# Sublime: change default syntax on a per-project basis

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I know you can change the default syntax associations globally with the "Open all with current extension as..." button in Sublime Text 3.

Can I make this change on a per-project basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's this extension I found: http://braindump.io/sublime-text/2014/09/26/project-specific-syntax-highlighting-in-sublime-text-3.html.

It's available in Package Control under the name "Project Specific Syntax Settings".